# Programmatically search a codedui uimap

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I have an object in a codedui uimap ... let's say it's

```
UIMap.Browser.Document.Table.Row.Cell
```

E.g., your code looks like this :

```
UITestControl testcontrol = this.UIMap.Browser.Document.Table.Row.Cell;
```

I need to find the object "Cell" as a fully qualified name, given a string *"Browser.Document.Table.Row.Cell".*

The result must be a UITestControl, so it can then be manipulated by the test.

The idea is, using the string containing the path, find the actual object in the uimap.

I can generate the string containing the "path" to the object, just can't figure out how to then search for it within the uimap, and link that back to a UITestControl.

(This is all from a C# standpoint)

e.g.,

```
String objectString = "Browser.Document.Table.Row.Cell";

UITestControl newcontrol = nameoffunctionweneed(objectString);
```

in this case, `nameoffunctionweneed` accepts a String, and outputs a UITestControl object.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem:

```
UITestControl nameoffunctionweneed(string path)
{
    object res = UIMap;
    foreach (var item in path.Split('.'))
    {
        res = res.GetType().GetProperty(item).GetValue(res, null);
    }
    return res as UITestControl;
}
```

Comment: Perfect - does exactly what it needs to do!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to work with the element directly given that paths can change very often. So, you'd work best with the simple CodedUI approach to searching for elements.

**Given:**

```
<html>
<body>
 <table>
   <tr>
       <td id="x1_y1"><span>hello World!</span></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Find the table cell by:**

```
var cellEle = new HtmlTableCell(browser);
cellEle.SearhProperties[HtmlTableCell.PropertyNames.Id] = "x1_y1";
// OR
cellEle.SearhProperties[HtmlTableCell.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "hello World!";
```